# I want to extract the parameters of a url in mysql

Tags: mysql

I have in my database a column with the parameters value of an url. I want with an sql query to put those parameters in different columns. I give an example:

I have now a column named parameters with for example this value: `pOrgNum=j11000&pLanguage=nl&source=homepage`

now I want three columns: `pOrgnum | pLanguage | source` with the values of my parameters.

The problem is that I don't know the order of my parameters or the length of it, so I can't use for example `substring(parameters,9,6)` to extract the parameter `pOrgnum`. can someone help me please?

Comment: Wouldn't this be easier to handle in the server-side language you're using, such as PHP/ASP or, based on your recent questions, Java?

Comment: Check out some of the answers here: http://superuser.com/a/288010/24444

Comment: Why don't you save your data in 3 columns? That's what I would do in your case. Instead of 1 called parameters 3 columns called pOrgnum | pLanguage | source.

Comment: You could do it with a regular expression (or three, in this case since you don't know the order).

Comment: I think the question is how to do it using mysql functions.

Comment: @ThanosK. I want to save it in 3 columns, but I get the url in one column of a certain table and I want to save it in another table with three columns.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There's a MySQL UDF that you can use to do exactly this, which also handles decoding the params and handles most character encodings, etc.

https://github.com/StirlingMarketingGroup/mysql-get-url-param

Examples

```
select`get_url_param`('https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=KDszSrddGBc','v');
-- "KDszSrddGBc"

select`get_url_param`('watch?v=KDszSrddGBc','v');
-- "KDszSrddGBc"

select`get_url_param`('watch?v=KDszSrddGBc','x');
-- null

select`get_url_param`('https://www.google.com/search?q=cgo+uint32+to+pointer&rlz=1C1CHBF_enUS767US767&oq=cgo+uint32+to+pointer&aqs=chrome..69i57.12106j0j7&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8','q');
-- "cgo uint32 to pointer"

select`get_url_param`('/search?q=Na%C3%AFvet%C3%A9&oq=Na%C3%AFvet%C3%A9','q');
-- "Naïveté"
```

<sub>Disclaimer, I am the author.</sub>

Answer (score 3):

I achieved this by taking the *right* of the string after the search parameter, then the *left* of the resulting string before the first &.

This handles

- if the parameter was the last in the url (so no "&" follows it)
- if the parameter does not exist (returns blank)
- varying lengths of the search string (provided you replace "utm_medium" everywhere)

This finds the value of "utm_medium" in a parameter named url:

```
IF(locate("utm_medium", url)=0, '', LEFT(RIGHT(url,length(url)-locate("utm_medium",url)-length("utm_medium")),IF(locate("&",RIGHT(url,length(url)-locate("utm_medium",url)-length("utm_medium")))=0,length(RIGHT(url,length(url)-locate("utm_medium",url)-length("utm_medium")+1)),locate("&",RIGHT(url,length(url)-locate("utm_medium",url)-length("utm_medium"))))-1)) utm_medium
```

To use, find and replace *url* with your field name, and utm_medium with your url parameter.

*May be inefficient, but gets the job done, and couldn't find an easy answer elsewhere*

Answer (score -1):

Its code work in mysql:

```
SELECT substring_index(URL_FIELD,'\',-1) FROM DemoTable;
```